# Picasso not loading image from http url but loads images from https url?

Tags: android, picasso

Picasso Loads the image fine if its from a https url like: `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/28uUsJ72a1A/hqdefault.jpg`

Since youtube directs all traffic through https this works to:
`http://i.ytimg.com/vi/28uUsJ72a1A/hqdefault.jpg`

But when I use my url
`http://www.example.com/images/djnsdfndsf.jpg`

it redircets the link to a https version of the site and just gives a error

This is how i'm loading the images
`Picasso.with(this).load(current.getImageURL()).into(ImageView);`

```
So I tried using this:
//Below code for Picasso initializing once for the app
private Picasso picasso;
private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
                .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient))
                .build();

//Below code to retrieve the images whereever required on the app
picasso.with(this).load(current.getImageURL()).into(imageView)
```

But Above code gives cannot resolve OkHttpDownloader

Right Now I'm using `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

**EDIT**
How do I force Picasso to download it over http not https?

Comment: picasso.with(this).load(current.getImageURL()).into(**ImageView**) here ImageView is your object or your class name>>

Comment: It's the Object

Answer (score 9):

HTTP requests are not allowed in API level 28+. To specifically allow HTTP requests to your domain, you must add the following file to your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">aravind.me</domain>       
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Add your domain name replacing **aravind.me** and add this file as **network_security_config.xml** in xml folder in resources.

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Add this to application tag in your manifest file.

Comment: if possible it's better to use https URL.

Answer (score 4):

Just try this:

> Replace `http` with `https` in your URL.

```
String aUrl = aImageInfo.getImage_url().replace("http", "https");

    Picasso
            .with(myContext)
            .load(aUrl)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.place_holder)
            .error(R.mipmap.error)
            .fit()
            .into(aHolder.aImageView);
```

Comment: hmm this wont work because the whole problem was that it is forced to use https which does not resolve, I need to force it to use http because my site does not have SSL.

Comment: Good one! I laugh a little bit, because I arrived here after searching through Picasso library to see what is happening there, and then I saw your answer and I was like "Ok, I don't care, this is the solution" :))

Comment: Why it should work? if the server redirect to https its meaningless

Comment: While this is more like hack, but seems like this is the only simple solution. And its a pity that Picasso doesn't mention it anywhere and leave everyone struggle to find a solution. On the other hand, Android 9, i.e. API 28 and above don't allow HTTP calls without adding new libraries and more boilerplate code in your app. There are some suggestions on this page which might work but I haven't tried them, I just changed my HTTP URLs to HTTPS and it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

By default `Picasso` is using `UrlConnectionDownloader`. From the name you can understand that it is using `HttpURLConnection` which won't automatically redirect from HTTP to HTTPS (or vice versa). Following the redirect may have serious security consequences.

The way to overcome this is to use [OkHttp3Downloader](https://github.com/JakeWharton/picasso2-okhttp3-downloader) - OkHttp 3 downloader implementation for Picasso 2.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient(); 
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
.downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
.build()
```

To use `OkHttp3Downloader` you have to add dependency

```
compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
```

Comment: this is not working anymore.

Answer (score -1):

If you want get a callback from Picasso then try the following
and `onBitmapLoaded()` set the bitmap to your ImageView

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).into(new Target() {
    @Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        // cache is now warmed up
    }
    @Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) { }
    @Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) { }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add this to your application class:

```
    final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .protocols(Collections.singletonList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
            .build();

    final Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
            .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
            .build();

    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
```

Answer (score -1):

CustomPicasso.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

/**
 * Created by Hrishikesh Kadam on 19/12/2017
 */

public class CustomPicasso {

    private static String LOG_TAG = CustomPicasso.class.getSimpleName();
    private static boolean hasCustomPicassoSingletonInstanceSet;

    public static Picasso with(Context context) {

        if (hasCustomPicassoSingletonInstanceSet)
            return Picasso.with(context);

        try {
            Picasso.setSingletonInstance(null);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "-> Default singleton instance already present" +
                    " so CustomPicasso singleton cannot be set. Use CustomPicasso.getNewInstance() now.");
            return Picasso.with(context);
        }

        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).
                downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(context))
                .build();

        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "-> CustomPicasso singleton set to Picasso singleton." +
                " In case if you need Picasso singleton in future then use Picasso.Builder()");
        hasCustomPicassoSingletonInstanceSet = true;

        return picasso;
    }

    public static Picasso getNewInstance(Context context) {

        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "-> Do not forget to call customPicasso.shutdown()" +
                " to avoid memory leak");

        return new Picasso.Builder(context).
                downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(context))
                .build();
    }
}
```

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
android {

    ...

}

dependencies {

    ...

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
}
```

Usage -

```
CustomPicasso.with(context)
    .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score -2):

Your url contains Https then you need to must be use https in url otherwise it will not load also you can't download image with normal http. If you want to try then just download http image using BitmapFactory.

Thanks.

Comment: So there is no possible way to use http?

Comment: No, in browser its automatically redirect http to https but in programmatic ally we need to set https.

Comment: What did you even just say here?