# Kotlin RecyclerView DataBindingAdapter I do not know why I get the error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I want to combine imageview with data bindingadapter. I was searching Google about my problem. The problem is databindingadapter doesn't work in my XML.

To put it easy, other views recognize well such as textView. If I enter a variable name at ImageView, the color should change but it will not change.

Here is my code
`<data class> (databindingadapter)`

```
import android.net.Uri
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class Person {

val name = ""
val age = ""
var image = ""

}

object imageBindingAdapter {

val person = Person()

@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("image")
fun bindImage(imageView: ImageView) {

    Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse(person.image))
        .fit().centerCrop().into(imageView)


}

}
```

**XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

<data>

    <variable name="person" 
type="com.example.kotlinerecyclerview.Person"/>

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               android:src="@android:drawable/btn_default"
               app:image="person.image"
    />

    <TextView
            android:text="@{person.name}"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(person.age)}"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/tv_age"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

**Here is my recyclerview adapter class**

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.kotlinerecyclerview.databinding.ItemBinding


class ListAdapter(val items: List<Person>, private val clickListener: 
(person: Person) -> Unit) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.SampleViewHolder>() {

class SampleViewHolder(val binding: ItemBinding) : 
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
SampleViewHolder {

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
    val holder = SampleViewHolder(ItemBinding.bind(view))

    view.setOnClickListener {
        clickListener.invoke(items[holder.adapterPosition])

    }


    return holder
}


override fun getItemCount() = items.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SampleViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.person = items[position]`enter code here`
}


}
```

I moved this code to another class ex) mainactivity, listadapter
but it doesn't work.

I wrote the code as described in other videos or documents about databindingadapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the Image Url also to the Binding Adapter

```java
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("image")
fun bindImage(imageView: ImageView, url: String) {

    Picasso.get().load(url)
        .fit().centerCrop().into(imageView)
}
```

Also change your xml as given below

```xml
<ImageView android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           android:src="@android:drawable/btn_default"
           app:image="@{person.image}"
    />
```

Check this [Guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#custom-logic) also

Answer (score 0):

First workaround:

1. Move binding adapter in separate file and add "app:"

ImageViewBindings.java

```
@BindingAdapter("app:image")
fun setImage(view: ImageView, url: String) {
   Picasso.get().load(url).fit().centerCrop().into(view)
}
```

2. In

```xml
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_default"
    app:image ="person.image"/>
```

android:src and app:image
try to do the same thing. It can be a reason of conflict.
If your's intent is set multiple images, consider to separate them (for example to 2 different ImageViews).

3. person.image is not an ObservableField so you should use executePendingBindings like

```java
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SampleViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.person = items[position]
    holder.binding.executePendingBindings()
}
```

Second workaround:

There is possibility what your urls use http protocol, not https.
In this case this link may help: [Picasso not loading image from http url but loads images from https url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500326/picasso-not-loading-image-from-http-url-but-loads-images-from-https-url/42500543#42500543)