# Picasso Image Isn't Working in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, picasso

I'm following this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktCpRGGfsls but the image isn't loading. I'm not sure why.

My java file:

```
mRestaurantTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleLabel);
        mRateCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rateCatLabel);
        mMainImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImage);

        Picasso
                .get()
                .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
                .into(mMainImage);
```

and xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleLabel"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pizza Shop"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rateCatLabel"
        android:text = "4.2 Italian"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        ></TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/rateCatLabel"
        android:layout_below="@id/titleLabel"
        >

    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` into manifest and implementation `com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828` into build.gradle (Module: app).

Comment: Try using HTTPS: `https://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png`.

Comment: Also, try converting this layout to Linear layout, your Picasso got seems fine. Also try running Picasso with context

Comment: HTTPS worked. Thank you! I'm using the exact layout that I took from the video which is relative, but I do know how to use linear a little bit. Is there a reason why I should be using that instead?

Comment: As you are just putting your views vertically thats why I suggested. Easier to understand. It goes case by case basis.

Comment: Interesting to know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500326/picasso-not-loading-image-from-http-url-but-loads-images-from-https-url

Comment: Okay I see. Thank you.