# url image download returns always null android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, httpurlconnection

What am I doing wrong? I get 200 OK response, but the image bitmap is `null`. I use `Asynctask` to retrieve url image. I am trying to assign the bitmap to imageview.

Any thoughts?

```
private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask< Void, Void, String> {


        protected String doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            loadingMore = true;
           
            
                Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
               
                try {
                    URL url1 = new URL("https://imgaz2.staticbg.com/thumb/view/oaupload/ser1/banggood/images/E4/21/c5424852-82af-47a1-8a13-54da3d1bc049.jpg");
                    HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
                    connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);
                    connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    int responceCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                    Log.i("response_line", Integer.toString(responceCode));
                    InputStream isstream =null;
                    isstream=connection.getInputStream();

                 //inputstream named isstream returns null
                    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(isstream);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

               

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe the resolution of the image is too big. Try a smaller image.

Comment: all images are like this...need to find a way...59kb is the image 300x300 size 300dpi

Comment: Have you considered Glide instead of using AsyncTask?  AsyncTask is deprecated.

Comment: Glide? is deprecated but can be used...the issue happens because of AsyncTask?

Comment: "Glide? is deprecated but can be used" -- Glide is not deprecated. `AsyncTask` is deprecated.

Comment: Yes i was referring to AsyncTask that is deprecated but can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)/[Picasso Github](https://github.com/square/picasso).

It allows you to do what you want in a few lines of code (**NB** watch out on Android 28+ *http* urls are a no go unless you do some [extra work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56884829/1133011)!):

```
Picasso.get().load("https://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

It handles the download, memory or disk caching and recycling of images, threading, placeholders, transformations and more. No need to reinvent the wheel. Heck you can even resize images and have various cropping options

```
Picasso.get()
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

**Update:**

As others have mentioned you shouldn't be using `AsyncTask` as its deprecated. There are many other libraries you can use to make network request in a threaded and more readable manner like [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley). This can be used in conjunction with Picasso to achieve what you want.

Below is an example which loads some text from google as well as an image when the text has been loaded:

[image]

**build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**fragment_first.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_first_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**FirstFragment.java:**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        String url = "https://www.google.com";

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        textView.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500));
                        Picasso.get().load("https://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                textView.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225064/discussion-on-answer-by-david-kroukamp-url-image-download-returns-always-null-an).